# What is the bluetooth library for Adafruit CLUE? Does one exist to download?

Tags: bluetooth, adafruit

I couldn't find any information on Adafruit CLUE's bluetooth library or even examples of code. Could someone tell me if Adafruit CLUE even has a bluetooth library and where I can find it?

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-clue/arcada-libraries

Comment: Please do some research and then ask a more focussed question (if necessary) before posting. Don't expect other people to Google, interpret and spoon feed answers when you haven't made a reasonable effort up front. I found this https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-multi-temperature-ble-monitoring/clue-circuitpython-libraries and a bunch of other references just by Googling "adafruit CLUE bluetooth library"

Answer (score 0):

Adafruit has circuitpython support for it: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_CLUE

The CLUE is just a bunch of sensors and an nRF52840. If you want to use it in an Arduino environment, I assume you can use the individual libraries for its components.

Comment: I am using it over on mu the editor for CircuitPython. I just want to know what the library name is.